# Why doesn't my function action get called?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I am trying to make a register user. In my component file there are the fields that fill the state and then on submit it should call the register function created in the action that afterwards should dispatch the response data and to type register success if it was successful otherwise register fail and dispatch the error. The point is that after filling the required fields and click on the register button does't call the function at all. in the inspection network doesn't show any function to be called. I am using webpack for the first time maybe this is a necessary detail for such issue.

This is the component:

```
const Register = ({register}) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        password: '',
        privacy: false
    });

    const {privacy} = formData;

    const onChange = e => {
        setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    };

    const onRegister = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (privacy){
            console.log('kari');
            register(formData);
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    };

    const onPrivacyCheck = () => {
        setFormData({...formData, privacy: !privacy})
    };

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div>
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form onSubmit={e => onRegister(e)}>
                    <input type={'text'} name={'first_name'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <input type={'text'} name={'last_name'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <input type={'text'} name={'phone'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <input type={'text'} name={'email'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <input type={'password'} name={'password'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type={'checkbox'} name={'privacy'} checked={privacy}
                           onClick={() => onPrivacyCheck()}/>
                    <label htmlFor="checkbox">Privacy Policy</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type={"submit"} value={'Register'}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
};

Register.propTypes = {
    register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {register})(Register);
```

this is the action:

```
export const register = (data) => async dispatch => {
    console.log(data);

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify(data);

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users', body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(setAlert('User registered successfully!', 'success'));
    } catch (e) {
        const errors = e.response.data.errors;

        if (errors) {
            errors.forEach(error => dispatch(
                setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')
            ));
        }

        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_FAIL
        });
    }
};
```

this is the reducer:

```
import {
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL,
    USER_LOADED,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    LOGOUT
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    const {type, payload} = action;

    switch (type) {
        case USER_LOADED:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                loading: false,
                user: payload
            };
        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                loading: false
            };
        case REGISTER_FAIL:
        case AUTH_ERROR:
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
        case LOGOUT:
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                loading: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not supposed to do any side effects within action creators the way you do. I guess, redux-thunk middleware is necessary for your action creators to make requests with axios.

Comment: Another thing that seems an issue to me is the way you connect `mapDispatchToProps` to your component. If you expect to trigger `onRegister` you should specify `const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({onRegister: data => dispatch(register(data))})`, or something like that and do `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my solution is, make your component Class, arrange your functions - add `this` and `this.setState` wherever needed and call registerData function form your action:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import {registerData} from "//Where the action file is"

class Register extends Component  {
    state= {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        password: '',
        privacy: false
    };


    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    };

    onRegister = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.privacy){
            console.log('kari');
            this.props.registerData(formData);
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    };

    onPrivacyCheck = () => {
        this.setState({ privacy: !privacy})
    };
   render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div>
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.onRegister}>
                    <input type={'text'} name={'first_name'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <input type={'text'} name={'last_name'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <input type={'text'} name={'phone'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <input type={'text'} name={'email'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <input type={'password'} name={'password'} onChange={e => onChange(e)}/>
                    <br/>
                    <input type={'checkbox'} name={'privacy'} checked={privacy}
                           onClick={() => this.onPrivacyCheck()}/>
                    <label htmlFor="checkbox">Privacy Policy</label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type={"submit"} value={'Register'}/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
 }
};

Register.propTypes = {
    register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
});



export default connect(mapStateToProps, {registerData})(Register);
```

In your form write the onSubmit function like this:

```
 <form onSubmit={this.onRegister}>
```

Modify your Action:

```
   export const registerData = data => dispatch => {
      const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
      axios
        .post('http://localhost:5000/api/users', data, config)
        .then(res => {
          dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
          });;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch({
            type: SET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response
          });
        });
    };
```

This should work

Comment: OP's `Register` is a **function component**, so there supposed to be no `this`. Isn't it?